# Three JS classes to one?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a tabbed form that loads with a fade in animation, the Next button does 3 things.

1. Takes you to the next tab (class '`sw-btn-next`', href '`#step-2`')
2. scrolls to the top of the page (class '`scrollToTop`')
3. Triggers the animation to start (class '`animatedClick`', data-target '`clickStep2`') on the page.

   `<button type="button" href="#step-2" data-target='clickStep2' class="animated fadeIn animatedClick btn btn-primary sw-btn-next float-right scrollToTop" data-id='5' data-sequence='1500'>Next</button>`

I think there must be a better way? I'm not very skilled in javascript.

*Moreover, since this code works... is there any way to make these animations only ever play once when triggered. If I go back a tab it starts the animation again.

---

scrollToTop JS

```
                                    $(document).ready(function(){

                                    //Click event to scroll to top
                                    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
                                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
                                        return false;
                                    });

                                });
```

sw-btn-next

```
            _setElements: function() {
            this.main.addClass("sw-theme-" + this.options.theme), this.nav.addClass("nav nav-tabs step-anchor").children("li").addClass("nav-item").children("a").addClass("nav-link"), this.options.anchorSettings.enableAllAnchors !== !1 && this.options.anchorSettings.anchorClickable !== !1 && this.steps.parent("li").addClass("clickable"), this.container.addClass("sw-container tab-content"), this.pages.addClass("tab-pane step-content");
            var e = this;
            return this.options.disabledSteps && this.options.disabledSteps.length > 0 && t.each(this.options.disabledSteps, function(t, i) {
                e.steps.eq(i).parent("li").addClass("disabled")
            }), this.options.errorSteps && this.options.errorSteps.length > 0 && t.each(this.options.errorSteps, function(t, i) {
                e.steps.eq(i).parent("li").addClass("danger")
            }), this.options.hiddenSteps && this.options.hiddenSteps.length > 0 && t.each(this.options.hiddenSteps, function(t, i) {
                e.steps.eq(i).parent("li").addClass("hidden")
            }), !0
        },
        _setToolbar: function() {
            if ("none" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarPosition) return !0;
            var e = this.options.toolbarSettings.showNextButton !== !1 ? t("<button></button>").text(this.options.lang.next).addClass("btn btn-primary sw-btn-next scrollToTop").attr("type", "button") : null,
                i = this.options.toolbarSettings.showPreviousButton !== !1 ? t("<button></button>").text(this.options.lang.previous).addClass("btn btn-secondary sw-btn-prev").attr("type", "button") : null,
                n = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-group mr-2 sw-btn-group").attr("role", "group").append(i, e),
                r = null;
            this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarExtraButtons && this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarExtraButtons.length > 0 && (r = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-group mr-2 sw-btn-group-extra").attr("role", "group"), t.each(this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarExtraButtons, function(t, e) {
                r.append(e.clone(!0))
            }));
            var a, o;
            switch (this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarPosition) {
                case "top":
                    a = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-toolbar hidden sw-toolbar sw-toolbar-top justify-content-" + this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition), a.append(n), "start" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition ? a.prepend(r) : a.append(r), this.container.before(a);
                    break;
                case "bottom":
                    o = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-toolbar hidden sw-toolbar sw-toolbar-bottom justify-content-" + this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition), o.append(n), "start" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition ? o.prepend(r) : o.append(r), this.container.after(o);
                    break;
                case "both":
                    a = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-toolbar hidden sw-toolbar sw-toolbar-top justify-content-" + this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition), a.append(n), "start" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition ? a.prepend(r) : a.append(r), this.container.before(a), o = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-toolbar sw-toolbar sw-toolbar-bottom justify-content-" + this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition), o.append(n.clone(!0)), null !== r && ("start" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition ? o.prepend(r.clone(!0)) : o.append(r.clone(!0))), this.container.after(o);
                    break;
                default:
                    o = t("<div></div>").addClass("btn-toolbar hidden sw-toolbar sw-toolbar-bottom justify-content-" + this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition), o.append(n), "start" === this.options.toolbarSettings.toolbarButtonPosition ? o.append(r) : o.append(r), this.container.after(o)
            }
            return !0
        },
```

Animation with http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/

Comment: "I think there must be a better way?"
Better for what? What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Just seems dirty. However I am looking for a way to make animations only appear once even if tabbed away.